# If true statement quits the program in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying this simple code. But It quits the program by doing nothing when the statement is true.
Why the program is behaving like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int hour,minute,second;
     
    printf( "Enter time (in HH:MM:SS) " );
    scanf( "%02d:%02d:%02d", &hour, &minute, &second );
    
    if ( scanf( "%02d:%02d:%02d", &hour, &minute, &second ) == 1 ) {
        printf( "Entered time is  %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second );
        printf( "Regular time is  %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour-12, minute, second ); 
    }
    else {
        printf( "Input is inapplicable" );
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: you're calling `scanf("%02d:%02d:%02d",&hour,&minute,&second)` twice

Comment: @phuclv you're right.It solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you meant

```
    printf("Enter time (in HH:MM:SS) ");
    
    if(scanf("%02d:%02d:%02d",&hour,&minute,&second) == 3){
```

The code you have cleary waits for more input after providing the time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All.This is working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
            
int main() {
            
 int hour,minute,second;
                 
 printf("Enter time (in HH:MM:SS) ");
                
 if(scanf("%02d:%02d:%02d",&hour,&minute,&second) == 3){
   printf("Entered time is  %02d:%02d:%02d\n",hour, minute, second);
   printf("Regular time is  %02d:%02d:%02d\n",hour-12, minute, second); 
   }
 else{
   printf("Input is inapplicable");
   }
                 
                
 return 0;   
             
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I predict the problem is that you set an if statement that would check if the values of minutes, hours and seconds equal 1 and it shouldn't be equaled to one, it should equal a different value.

**if(scanf("%02d:%02d:%02d",&hour,&minute,&second) == 1)- This is a wrong part**

*it should be if(scanf("%02d:%02d:%02d",&hour,&minute,&second) >= 1)*

Comment: `>= 1` is still wrong